# Faster MySQL method for this query using IN with check on count?

Tags: mysql, sql-in

I'm working on a video database that is linked with tags, when I execute this query I need to wait a long time, it creates a temporary table and such, but I think this should have a faster way:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  `video_id` 
FROM  `video_tag_link` 
WHERE  `tag_id` 
IN (
'2752',  '36370'
)
GROUP BY  `video_id` 
HAVING COUNT(  `video_id` ) =2
LIMIT 0 , 20

MySQL Result: 1
SIMPLE
video_tag_link
range
PRIMARY,video_id
PRIMARY
4
NULL
300268
Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

Mysql table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video_tag_link` (
  `video_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`,`video_id`),
  KEY `video_id` (`video_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Total of 45mil records in this table.
```

Anyone that can help me with this query?

Comment: Don't compare integers to strings

Comment: @shA.t; error, Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables

Comment: Have you indexed 'tag_id` colum ?

Comment: Yes @RajeshK as its a primary key and they are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with tag ids as integers

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  `video_id` 
FROM  `video_tag_link` 
WHERE  `tag_id` 
**IN (2752,  36370)**
GROUP BY  `video_id` 
HAVING COUNT(  `video_id` ) =2
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Comment: Yes i´ve tried, but no difference, i think mysql will convert the string to integer..

Comment: The index is not getting selected, the "rows" is coming as null. Either the two tag id forms the majority of the records or you table is messed. Try ANALYZE TABLE and FORCE INDEX

Comment: Thanks, this worked
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE  `video_id` 
FROM  `video_tag_link` 
FORCE INDEX (`video_id`)
WHERE  `tag_id` 
IN (2752,  36370)
GROUP BY  `video_id` 
HAVING COUNT(`video_id` ) =2
LIMIT 0 , 20

Comment: @EricBruggema, Please mark it as answered if your problems are fixed.

Comment: Hi, not quite.. the query doesn't use temporary tables but is still so super slow, i've tested multiple setups but still freeking slow. Only 48Mil records to search... takes for 2 tags more then 2 seconds, for 3 tags more then 20 seconds and for 4 tags more then 1 minute... i need this to get way lower...

Comment: Please see the explain, "Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort" . Its internally creating the temp table(as data cannot be held in memory) and file sort which is making it slow